# Match dash if inside a compound word containing only letters (no digits)

Tags: regex

I want to have regex that let me find dashes only if the words behind and after have only letters, (so that I would replace those dashes by spaces). So, for example, I would not want to put a space in a middle of a product code (that could contain some special characters or numbers).

How can I find all hyphens that separates words containing only letters?

```
no- -no 00-00 no 0-no no-0 0nono-nono0 yes-yes yes-yes-yes
  x x     x       x     x       x         ^       ^   ^
```

Attempt:

```
\b(?<!([\d\W]))-(?!([\d\W]))\b
```

https://www.regextester.com/?fam=105652

Thanks!

Comment: What regex tool/language you are you using here?

Comment: java language (lucene library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
\b[A-Za-z]+(?:-+[A-Za-z]+)+\b
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation:

```
\b[A-Za-z]+        - match an initial word containing only letters
(?:-+[A-Za-z]+)+   - followed by 1+ some number of hyphens and another all letters word
\b                 - the final word also ends in a word boundary
```

If you really needed to match the dashes only, we could try using variable width lookarounds:

```
(?<=\b[A-Za-z]+)-(?=[A-Za-z]+\b)
```

But, this won't even work in the regex demo above, because it does not support variable width lookbehinds.

**Edit:**

You actual problem appears now to be that you want to replace these matching dashes with spaces.  If so, then do a find on the following pattern:

```
\b([A-Za-z]+)-(?=[A-Za-z]+\b)
```

And then replace with:

```
$1    <-- space after $1
```

Comment: Thanks though I want to match only the dashes. not the words.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that, because you would have to look variable width lookbehinds, which most regex engines do not even support.  You should edit your question and tell us the actual problem.  I think my answer can be made viable for what you need here.

Comment: @leontalbot Check my **edit** above.  If Lucene supports regex replacement with capture groups, my answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

To match *just the dashes*, you can use:

```
(?:(?<= )|\G)[a-z]+\K-(?=(?:[a-z]+-)*[a-z]+\b)
```

https://regex101.com/r/6lkTmn/4

It's a bit tricky and requires `\G` (matches position at end of last match) and `\K` ("forgets" anything matched up until now). Breaking it down, from the start:

`(?:(?<= )|\G)` - Match either a position right after a space (beginning of a word), or match the *end of the previous match* (indicating that we're in the middle of a compound word). (Can't use `\b` instead of the lookbehind because `\b` will match the position between a `-` and a letter)

`[a-z]+` - Match the initial characters in the compound word (no digits)

`\K` - This is how we avoid variable-length lookbehind - it forgets all previously matched characters.

`-` - Match the dash

`(?=(?:[a-z]+-)*[a-z]+\b)` - Lookahead for alphabetical characters, possibly interspersed with dashes. This is necessary to avoid matching compound words that begin with a valid format, but end in an invalid format, like `-nono0`.